# why this.static_variable not giving error when this refer to instance variable not Class in java

Tags: java, class, static, instance

```
   class Test {
    int instance_variable ;
    static int static_variable  = 15;

    Test(int abc){
        this.instance_variable = abc;
    }

   static void sget (){
       System.out.println(static_variable);
    }

    void get(){

        System.out.println(this.static_variable + " from static ");
        System.out.println(instance_variable + " from instance  ");
        this.static_variable = 90;
    }
}

public class ABC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test(10);
        Test t2 = new Test(13);
        t1.get();
        t2.get();

//        Output
//        15 from static from obj
//        10 from instance from obj
//        90 from static from obj
//        13 from instance from obj
    }
}
```

As you can see I am able to use `this.static_variable`.

I have debugged the program and I have seen this doesn't not contain static variable when how it is able to give value of static variable?

It should throw error on this line and I am also able to print a static variable from instance method void get .

Comment: "It should throw error on this line" why do you think it should?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). To wit: *"You can also refer to static fields with an object reference like `myBike.numberOfBicycles` but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class variables."* . "Discouraged" doesn't mean "syntactically wrong" :)

Comment: i want to know how this keyword is able to fetch value of Class variable in this scenario because this doesn't hold static variable then how it is doing ?

Comment: If the variable were an object, your theory would be correct, but it is a primitive.

Comment: Every instance knows its class. You can use `getClass()` method to get the class. `this.getClass()` will give you the Test class.

Comment: *"`this` doesn't hold static variable"* again, you're starting from a wrong premise. Class variables are accessible by any instance of that class, including `this`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of error in the above code.Static members always have global scope. Passing value to global variable using constructor is nothing wrong at all.Even not refering through this keyword will also yield the same result. 'this' keyword points to instance variable inshort global variable.So. the same definition of this will be maintained for static variable too.